# Why am I getting a Maximum function nesting level error when running phpunit?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, xdebug

I am getting the following error when I try to run phpunit.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /Users/user/Development/Web/ProjectFlyer/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/ConnectionInterface.php on line 3
```

I have one test:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class FlyersControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function it_shows_the_form_to_create_a_new_flyer()
    {
        $this->visit('/flyers/create');
    }
}
```

My routes file contains:

```
Route::get('{zip}/{street}', 'FlyersController@show');
Route::resource('flyers', 'FlyersController');
```

This should produce one failed test because the show route is overwriting the resource for create. Instead it's giving me the maximum function nesting level error.

If I fix the routing issue, and run phpunit, I get:

```
OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: I think your test flow is not complete , Take a quick look here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#application-testing

Comment: This is not it. I'm following an example from laracasts that works fine for him without anything else. For the sake of argument, I added ->see('Text in page'); but get the same error.

Comment: Have tried to raise xdebug.max_nesting_level value in your php.ini ? or can you check if xdebug is properly loaded

Comment: Do you have any middleware set up for this Controller? Can be that the auth middleware (or other) is creating a redirect loop or something

Comment: Just the web middleware

Comment: How is your FlyersController@create looks like ?

Comment: It literally only returns a view.

Comment: I've just had the same problem. This laracasts thread helped [it's a xdebug issue] https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-maximum-function-nesting-level-of-100-reached-aborting